# Group By Two Relations and Sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a ruby on rails application that has three models: `transaction`, `event_section` and `account`. A transaction belongs to exactly one event_section and one account. In the model of the `transaction` I have a method `sum` to get the sum of the transaction, it uses multiple fields of the model. (It adds `amount_coins`, `amount_bills` and `amount_rolls`)

My schema looks as follows:

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",           limit: 255
    t.text     "description",     limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

  create_table "event_sections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title",       limit: 255
    t.text     "description", limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.integer  "account_id",          limit: 4
    t.integer  "amount_bills",        limit: 4
    t.decimal  "amount_coins",        precision: 64, scale: 2
    t.integer  "amount_rolls",        limit: 4
    t.integer  "event_section_id",    limit: 4
  end

  add_index "transactions", ["account_id"], name: "fk_rails_01f020e267", using: :btree
  add_index "transactions", ["event_section_id"], name: "fk_rails_b5ed204601", using: :btree
```

Now I want to efficiently generate a table with the `accounts` and the `event_sections` as rows and columns, the cells should be the sums of the `sum` function of all transactions having the corresponding `event_section` and `account`.

```
       |  ES1    | ES2       |
|------|---------|-----------|
| Acc1 | 845.00  |  1'285.00 |
| Acc2 | 1080.00 |    345.00 |
```

To obtain this table, the following sample data would be in the database:

```
Account.create(title: "Acc1") -> id = 1
Account.create(title: "Acc2") -> id = 2

EventSection.create(title: "ES1") -> id = 1
EventSection.create(title: "ES2") -> id = 2

Transaction.create(amount_coins: 10, amount_bills: 500, amount_rolls: 15, account_id: 1, event_section_id: 1)
Transaction.create(amount_coins: 10, amount_bills: 300, amount_rolls: 10, account_id: 1, event_section_id: 1)
Transaction.create(amount_coins: 30, amount_bills: 700, amount_rolls: 30, account_id: 2, event_section_id: 1)
Transaction.create(amount_coins: 10, amount_bills: 300, amount_rolls: 10, account_id: 2, event_section_id: 1)

Transaction.create(amount_coins: 10, amount_bills: 300, amount_rolls: 35, account_id: 1, event_section_id: 2)
Transaction.create(amount_coins: 30, amount_bills: 900, amount_rolls: 10, account_id: 1, event_section_id: 2)
Transaction.create(amount_coins: 25, amount_bills: 300, amount_rolls: 20, account_id: 2, event_section_id: 2)
```

(Of course I can write an double for loop, but I know that that is not efficient. I could also just write the plain SQL, but as everybody says you should use the rails magic if you can.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza ok, I added the information needed I think.